# How to gracefully handle sql injection in Spring data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Affected:

1. Spring Data JPA 1.10.2, 1.9.4
2. Other unsupported versions are also affected

Spring:

https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2016-6652

http://cve.circl.lu/cve/CVE-2016-6652

**Mitigation**:

Users of affected versions should apply the following mitigation:

1. Users are advised to upgrade to Spring Data JPA in version 1.10.4
   (Hopper SR4) or 1.9.6 (Gosling SR6). These versions contain
   sanitizing of the Sort instances handed to the data access layer and
   only allow referring to domain object fields and aliases used in the
   JPQL backing the query method.
2. Should users still need to hand complex sort expressions to the data
   access layer, they can use the newly introduced JpaSort.unsafe(…) to
   reinstantiate the old behavior.

**Question:**

We are using latest version of Spring data but security assessment tool shows that  Sql injection vulnerability in code , should we start using OWASP ESAPI API on Repo level ?

Comment: Assessment tools are not always correct. They can point to potential problems. If you are using a good tool, it will give you attack vectors you can try. You will have to try those vectors manually on the pages reported as affected and see if injection is really successful. If not, don't worry about the tool-generated warnings.

Comment: And if you do confirm a vulnerability, please open an issue with the affected library, so it can get fixed.